# What would you call these 3D planes?

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d

I want to call these 3D planes '**Cartesian planes**':

[image]

But maybe that is incorrect as the Cartesian plane is traditionally just the XY plane with a third perpendicular (unnamed) one.

Is there another name for what I'm thinking of?

Comment: They are called coordinate planes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the commenters said, they are called coordinate planes, in analogy to coordinate axes.  Examples of this usage are at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system, https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/raylee/SM223/Ch12_1_Stewart(2016).pdf, [https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat267/examples/xyz_coordinate_system_2.pdf](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Esurgent/mat267/examples/xyz_coordinate_system_2.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for!